# Plotting different groups of a dataframe in different subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, group-by

I want to plot 4 different scatter subplots in one main plot. The data are coming from a grouped dataframe which is read from a .csv file. The initial dataframe looks like this:

```
df.to_csv("File.csv", index=False)
```

df:

|  | Category1 | Category2 | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | x | 4 | 5.1 |
| 1 | B | x | 3 | 4.2 |
| 2 | A | y | 2 | 7.1 |
| 3 | A | z | 9 | 6.1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 97 | A | z | 4 | 5.1 |
| 98 | A | w | 3 | 4.2 |
| 99 | B | y | 2 | 7.1 |
| 100 | B | z | 9 | 6.1 |

As you can see, category1 has only two kinds of values (A,B) while category2 has 4 kinds of values (x,y,z,w). the X and Y values are random and for display purpose only.

The grouped df was created using following command:

```
dfGrouped = df.groupby(["Category1 ","Category2"])
```

dfGrouped:

|  |  | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 4 | 5.1 |
| A |  | 7 | 9.1 |
|  | y | 3 | 4.2 |
|  |  | 3 | 4.2 |
|  |  | 3 | 4.2 |
|  | z | 2 | 7.1 |
|  | w | 9 | 6.1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| B | x | 4 | 5.1 |
|  | y | 3 | 4.2 |
|  | z | 2 | 7.1 |
|  |  | 2 | 7.1 |
|  | w | 9 | 6.1 |

I tried to plot them individually, but it didn't work:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.margins(0.05)
for name, group in dfGrouped:
    ax.plot(group.X, group.Y, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=2, label=name)
```

I even tried to call the groups using get_group but I was not successful.

```
dfGrouped= dfGrouped.get_group(("A","x"))
```

Is there any way to plot 4 different scatter subplots (Based on "category2": x,y,z,w) in one main plot in a way that each plot contains 2 sets values with 2 different colors(Based on "Category1": A, B)?

Comment: What variables are you interested in plotting for each group? X and Y?

Comment: @liorr that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot):

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category1': np.random.choice(['A','B'], size=100),
                   'Category2': np.random.choice(['w','x', 'y', 'z'], size=100),
                   'x': np.random.random(size=100),
                   'y': np.random.random(size=100),
                   })
# plot
sns.relplot(data=df, x='x', y='y', col='Category2', col_wrap=2, hue='Category1')
```

Output:
[image: seaborn relplot]

Answer (score 0):

I used scatter plot, below is another alternative:

```
**DataFrame**   

       col1     val1    val2    col2
  0     A      1000     5000     w
  1     A      3000     4000     w
  2     A      7000     5000     w
  3     A      3000     4000     w
  4     A      5000     6000     x
  5     A      5000     4000     x
  6     A      5000     9000     x
  7     A      6000     10000    x
  8     B      5000     6000     y
  9     B      5000     4000     y
  10    B      5000     9000     y
  11    A      6000     10000    y
  12    A      5000     6000     z
  13    B      5000     4000     z
  14    B      5000     9000     z
  15    A      6000     10000    z
```

**Function**

```
def plot_grouped_data():
  fig = plt.figure()
  fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
  i=0
  for label, df in new.groupby('col2'):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i+1)
    # print(label)
    sns.scatterplot(data=df,x= 'val1', y='val2', hue='col1', ax=ax)
    plt.title(f'Title={label}')
    plt.legend(loc="upper right")
    i += 1
  plt.show()

plot_grouped_data()
```

**Output**

[image: plot]

Comment: it works, thanks, but CPU consuming, right?

Comment: might be...since for loop is involved. Just an other answer!